# Calculating the Mass of Earth's Atmosphere

Tags: fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, oceanography

I am trying to solve the problem below:

> Calculate the mass of the Earth's atmosphere given a mean pressure at the surface of $1.013\times 10^5$ Pa and $g=9.81$ m/s/s.

I have been provided a hint in the textbook to use the hyrdostatic equation. From my understanding, the hyrdostatic equation is of the form $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}=-\rho g.$$Here, $\rho$ denotes density and thus $$\rho=\frac{m}{v}\implies \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}=-\frac{mg}{v}.$$I am unsure of how to proceed. Any **tips** would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is much simpler than that. See [Why does the air pressure at the surface of the earth exactly equal the weight of the entire air column above it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139346)

Comment: That pressure is the same as 14.7 psi, so just multiply by the surface area of the earth in in^2 to get the mass in lb.

Comment: @ChetMiller Why though? I am not concerned with  the numerical complexities of the question, but rather the understanding of the theory behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure at the earth's surface is the force per unit area needed to support the weight of the column of air above that area, extending from the surface to outer space.  So the mass of the column per unit area is equal to the pressure divided by g.

Comment: I have derived the following for the entire atmosphere $$\text{mass}=\frac{\text{pressure}\times\text{surface area}}{\text{g}}.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up integrating from $z$ to $\infty$ and realised that $$\int_{z}^{\infty} \rho \ dz$$ was just the mass per unit area of the atmospheric column.